# Append data after every code run to next two consecutive columns in already created excel using java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I m writing code for some report generation. I am using apache poi jars and java for reading and writing data in excels. I have input as well as output excels (report excels). Now I am able to run first run correctly for output excel with correct data. Now, I want to append new data in next two consecutive columns keeping previous rows and columns data as it is. Could anyone help how can I append data to columns keeping previous data in excel in java ?`
Thanks

```
XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(r);  

row.createCell(0).setCellValue(data1); 
row.createCell(1).setCellValue(data2);
row.createCell(2).setCellValue(data3);  
row.createCell(3).setCellValue(data4);
row.createCell(4).setCellValue(data5);

r++; 

FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(excelFileName);           
wb.write(fileOut);
```

After first run, for every next run it should only add last two column values in excel keeping previous data.

Comment: ``if(row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue() != null) { ... }`` ?

Comment: How about only creating the cells you need and not touching the existing ones?

Comment: Find out how many rows a sheet has and how many cells each row has, then append new rows and cells... There are methods like [`getPhysicalNumberOfRows`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html#getPhysicalNumberOfRows--) and [`getPhysicalNumberOfCells`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFRow.html#getPhysicalNumberOfCells--)...

Comment: @XtremeBaumer , as I said its report excel I have to print other data only once and last two result columns repeatatively.

Comment: @deHaar  thanks , can you please help me with the code for append ? I have 30 rows totally and 5 columns for first run i.e. till E30 , how to give condition to ignore this E30 data ?

Answer (score 0):

You can append data to a sheet that has an unkown amount of existing columns like

```
XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells());
cell.setCellValue(dataN);
```

because the method tells you how many cells a row already has, which is the first index of cells that is not existing.
Your part should now be finding out how to do that in a loop for more than one additional cell in a row.

If you want to append new rows, then do it this way:

```
XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows());
```

Comment: Thanks , this is helpful to get next row/column in excel now Problem is I am not getting the condition to ignore already existing data to add new data

Comment: Well, that might have to involve a comparison of the cell content from `row.getCell(0)` to `row.getCell(row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells() - 1)` with the data to be written...